# Create reference array of structs with one mutable field

Tags: arrays, rust, vector

I have a set of return values via a serial connection that is read in as an array of `u8`. For the sake of illustration, let's say we have this struct which defines the attributes of the returned array:

```
pub struct Event<'a> {
    pub event_code: u8,
    pub description: &'static str,
    pub data: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
    pub crc: &'a mut [u8; 2],
}
```

The event code is static and known at compile time, as is the description. The data is always items `4` through `data.len() - 2`, and the CRC is always the last two bytes in the transmission. The thing is, I know what all of the types of event code returns are, so I want to create a reference array:

```
pub static EVENTS_REF: [Event; 115] = [
   ...
];
```

That holds the predefined instantiations of all of the structs with their static values set. The issue becomes the lack of ability to have an &mut field in the structs that are predefined in the reference array. I will not necessarily know what the size of the data array (or `Vec` in this instance) will be, I know the size of the CRC but the values contained within it need to be mutable as they will not be known until they are read in from the serial connection. Is there a relatively cogent (and idiomatic) way of handling this sort of a use case? There is no multi-threading so collisions as of now are not a concern.

**edit**
As an example of one of the arrays of structs that this program uses, this is what it would look like to use a local variable:

```
let events_ref: [Event; 115] = [
GameEvent { event: 0x00, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x00)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x01, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x01)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x11, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x11)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x12, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x12)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x13, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x13)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x14, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x14)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x15, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x15)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x16, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x16)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x17, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x17)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x18, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x18)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x19, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x19)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x1a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x1a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x1b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x1b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x1c, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x1c)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x1d, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x1d)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x1e, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x1e)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x1f, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x1f)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x20, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x20)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x21, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x21)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x22, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x22)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x23, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x23)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x24, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x24)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x25, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x25)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x27, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x27)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x28, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x28)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x29, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x29)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x2a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x2a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x2b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x2b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x2c, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x2c)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x2d, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x2d)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x2e, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x2e)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x31, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x31)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x32, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x32)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x33, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x33)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x34, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x34)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x35, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x35)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x36, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x36)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x37, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x37)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x38, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x38)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x39, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x39)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x3a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x3a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x3b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x3b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x3c, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x3c)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x3d, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x3d)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x3e, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x3e)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x3f, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x3f)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x40, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x40)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x41, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x41)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x42, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x42)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x43, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x43)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x44, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x44)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x45, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x45)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x46, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x46)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x47, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x47)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x48, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x48)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x49, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x49)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x4a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x4a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x4b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x4b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x4c, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x4c)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x4d, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x4d)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x4e, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x4e)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x4f, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x4f)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x50, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x50)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x51, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x51)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x52, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x52)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x53, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x53)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x54, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x54)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x55, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x55)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x56, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x56)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x57, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x57)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x60, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x60)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x61, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x61)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x66, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x66)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x67, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x67)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x68, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x68)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x69, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x69)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x6a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x6a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x6b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x6b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x6c, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x6c)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x6d, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x6d)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x6e, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x6e)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x6f, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x6f)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x70, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x70)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x71, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x71)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x72, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x72)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x74, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x74)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x75, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x75)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x76, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x76)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x77, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x77)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x78, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x78)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x79, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x79)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x7a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x7a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x7b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x7b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x7c, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x7c)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x7e, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x7e)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x7f, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x7f)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x80, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x80)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x81, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x81)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x82, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x82)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x83, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x83)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x84, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x84)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x85, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x85)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x86, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x86)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x87, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x87)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x88, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x88)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x89, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x89)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x8a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x8a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x8b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x8b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x8c, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x8c)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x8e, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x8e)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x8f, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x8f)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x98, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x98)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x99, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x99)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x9a, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x9a)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
GameEvent { event: 0x9b, description: "Description string (always the same for event 0x9b)", data: &mut [0; 32], crc: &mut [0x00, 2],},
];
```

There are 8 of these reference arrays with similar structures and lengths, each only has 1 or 2 mutable fields that will be read in when the program is running; the rest are truly static in the sense that they will not change. Having 8 of these local variables with hundreds of items that largely never change seems to be frivolous, but maybe I'm just too dense to realize why it would be so necessary.

Comment: What are you using `EVENTS_REF` for? Why are you storing references instead of an owned `Vec` and `[u8; 2]`? Statics have to be thread-safe in Rust. If you want to make something that isn't thread-safe, the easiest way is to use local data instead.

Comment: I am using it as a store for the default values to all possible events. The only mutable characteristics of these events are the data field and the crc values, so it seems onerous to have a local variable in my main function that initializes multiple arrays with hundreds of values inside of them. The reason I was storing references was just to try and get something to compile, as I wanted to avoid the scenario of having the huge never changing (from a human code frame of reference) default local variables in my main loop just because two fields don't have known sizes at compile time.

Comment: Both of those types have known sizes at compile time. Maybe you meant to do `data: &'a [u8]`? That would make a lot more sense than `Vec`.  I think it would help to show what the reading process looks like, or at least a complete program that reconstructs the never-changing values every time, so we can help you speed it up.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, although the sizes are known the contents are not. They need to be mutable so they can be changed during the life of the program, but like you pointed out, the most prevalent way I've seen of doing that is making it a local variable. I was trying to avoid that at all cost. I'll update with a more concrete example to hopefully elucidate why that was a concern for me.

Comment: You can create a struct `struct EventStatic { event_code: u8, description: &'static str }`, and include a `&'static EventStatic` field in `Event`.